# how to compare the current record to the next in the same table in terms of 'datetime' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, compare

Problem: I’m going to explain this problem using the Sakila sample database and it data so it is easier for you. Ok, so my question is how can I compare the current record to the next in the same table in terms of 'datetime'. This is how the table looks like:

```
 payment_id  customer_id     staff_id    rental_id   amount  payment_date    last_update

1   1   1   76       2.99   25/05/2005 11:30:37 15/02/2006 22:12:30
2   1   1   573      0.99   28/05/2005 10:35:23 15/02/2006 22:12:30
3   1   1   1185     5.99   15/06/2005 00:54:12 15/02/2006 22:12:30
4   1   2   1422     0.99   15/06/2005 18:02:53 15/02/2006 22:12:30
5   1   2   1476     9.99   15/06/2005 21:08:46 15/02/2006 22:12:30
```

Using the above explanation in this sample, for each **‘staff_id’**, how can I compare the current row with the next (using ‘payment_date’ for current and next), so it brings only the **pair of records** where the amount of the current record is the same as the next (something like current.amount = next.amount). This means that each record should be compared to the next of the same ‘staff_id’, and so on.

I’m currently using this query, which do the job, but it **takes for ever**. I know it works good because I setted LIMIT 3 and it brought the correct ones (you can test it as well if you have the Sakila sample database):

```
SELECT * FROM payment a 
JOIN payment b ON a.staff_id = b.staff_id AND a.payment_date > b.payment_date AND a.amount =         b.amount
LEFT JOIN payment c ON a.staff_id = c.staff_id AND c.payment_date < a.payment_date AND    c.payment_date > b.payment_date
WHERE c.payment_id IS NULL
LIMIT 3;
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: have you looked at a correlated subquery? its can also be slow but may be faster than those joins...

Comment: Since you have a working query, have you tried to optimize it?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Hi, the problem I faced with correlated subqueries is that it doesn't bring paired records. I need the two matched records together.

AgRizzo How can I do that?

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` command to make sure you are using an index

Comment: @AgRizzo This what I get by adding EXPLAIN to the query above, I could't format it properly: 
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'a', 'ALL', 'idx_fk_staff_id', NULL, NULL, NULL, '16086', NULL
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'b', 'ref', 'idx_fk_staff_id', 'idx_fk_staff_id', '1', 'sakila.a.staff_id', '4021', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'c', 'ref', 'idx_fk_staff_id', 'idx_fk_staff_id', '1', 'sakila.a.staff_id', '4021', 'Using where; Not exists'